# Enable intellisense for inactive code region

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Looking for tips regarding doing C# with visual studio.

I need a way to enable intellisense for code between pre-processor #if/#endif.

Normally such code is greyed out, How can i disable this greying out.

Even though the code is not being compiled i still need intellisense  on the code.

Cheers

Comment: Best I could find is adding a new configuration in the configuration manager, assuming the condition in your preprocessor #if is based on the presence (or absence) of a symbol. You then just have to switch between configurations when you want to work on the disabled portion of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actually**, if you want to get the intellisense for the gray part, you only have to make the condition of the gray part to be `true`. And there is no other way to realize it.

If you use the pre-processor in a specific configuration, you can try the following two suggestions to get the intellisense.

**Suggestion**

In my side, the `test` is defined under `DefineConstant` of **Debug**.

[image]

**1)** change the condition of the two parts and when you modiy the first part, make the condition of it to `true`.

[image]

**2)** or create a new **Configuration** called **Test** which does not have such **pre-processor** and when you modify the gray part, just change to Configuration to **Test**, and then you can modify the gray part.